# Find the number of people in the family

Tags: logic, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

PRE-RMO 2014 question 14 (set-A)

One morning,each member of Manjul's family drank an 8-ounce mixture of coffee with milk. The amounts of coffee and milk varied from cup to cup, but were never zero. Manjul drank $\frac17 ^{th}$ of the total amount of milk and $\frac2{17} ^{th}$ of the total amount of coffee. How many people are in the family?

---

What I did: let total milk = x and coffee = y.
Therefore after removal of Manjul's share milk: 102x/119 and coffee = 105y/119.
HCF (GCD) of (102,105) is 3. Therefore number of people = 3+1.
Which is probably wrong because I didn't use the total amount of mixture anywhere... And after I tried placing y in terms of x I got a messy equation, which gave different HCF for different value of x<8.

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: I dont understand... it maybe any amount of members on this family because you can create infinite-uncountable portions of coffee and milk.

Comment: No. Somewhere HCF (GCD) would place a limit.

Comment: I cant understand... GCD of what quantities? You can create, from $\frac17$ and $\frac{2}{17}$ infinite countable GCD with any other number that you choose for free.

Comment: Even I had thought about this, but probably it would be wrong to say that. One can't have infinite number of people in a family. And I'm not sure of my method, if you find it wrong you can continue solving it in your way. :) Also, two numbers have unique GCD.

Comment: *Or fractions in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we have $x+y = 8n$ and $\dfrac x7 + \dfrac{2y}{17}=8$, where $x, y \in \mathbb R^+$ and $n \in \mathbb N$.

$$\implies 17x + 14y = 952 \implies 3x+112n=952 \quad \text{and } y = -952+120n$$

Now $x> 0 \implies n \le 8$ and $y > 0 \implies n \ge 8$, so ...

Comment: Why is x + y not equal to 8? The total amount of mixture is 8.

Comment: It should be $8$ times the number of people in the family, as each person drank $8$ ounces.

Answer (score 0):

If 6 more member take same amount as manjul 3/17 coffee will be left

1+6=7
3 coffee which is left,
2coffee + 1 milk = 8ounce
so let us assume 2 coffee is gone but no milk is left hence this 1 left coffee will be drank by the same person
7+1=8
So 8 persons